# Nginx + PHPcurl?

Tags: php, nginx, curl

I have a misterious problem :
I have a local web server (nginx) and I try to fetch from outside web hosting (planetHoster).
When I type "http://myIp:8080/" in my browser it works.
When I use command line curl "curl -L http://myIp:8080/" it works.
When I curl (PHP one) on "http://example.com" it works.
But when I curl (PHP one) on "http://myIp:8080/" it fails ("Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8000: Connection refused").
Here is the code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myIp:8000");
$curl = curl_init();
$params = [
    'title' => 'Welcome Bro !',
    'body' => 'Lorem Ipsum etc etc',
    'user' => 'marc'
];
$params_string = http_build_query($params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // suivre les redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<br>";
echo $output;
```

Does anyone have an idea about this ?
Thanks & good day!

Comment: You need your router to configure with port forwarding to the machine where your local server runs on.

Comment: it can be firewall issue.please check that if that is an issue or not

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I have no error from nginx logs; just the curl one "Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8000: Connection refused". since I can connect "manually" with typing the adress on the browser or via command line curl It shoudn't be a firewall/port forwarding problem is it ?